# USS class color background not functional

Tags: unity, unity-ui

Dealing with UI Builder for created interface button, I need to change properties background color with uss class stylesheet.

I created a class stylesheet .buttonControl which drag'n drop into button and I change properties of this class into inspector into : inspector > Background > Color

I try also to change this background color directly into button inspector properties but this result is the same.

Screenshoot exemple with background class

[image: Class uss properties]

Screenshoot with object properties

[image: Object properties]

All of those action never change background color button.

**What's happen ? What is the trap ? Why background color never change in this context ?**